# Копии класса, их объявление Java

Tags: java, классы, объявление

Я новичок в java, пытаюсь сделать многопользовательскую игру. Сервер, клиент есть, проблема в другом.
У меня есть класс, допустим Game, в ней находятся функции для отрисовки персонажа, и всякие другие методы. Проблема такова, что для каждого отдельного игрока нужен свой такой класс. В другом классе, допустим Play, я могу брать копии моего Game строчкой Private static Game Player1;
Так вот, собственно вопрос, как мне сделать так, чтобы при подключении создавался, допустим Player2, потом Player3... Player499999? Или быть может вы подскажите, как сделать лучше? Пишу на libgdx

Comment: цикл? и массив.

Comment: Приведите пример, пожалуйста. Я не знаю, сколько будет игроков на сервере, мне описывать 1000 копий моего класса Game? А если игроков будет 1001?

Comment: Для этого есть ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Добавить поле в класс во время выполнения(runtime) нельзя. Для того чтобы хранить данные обычно используются [простые массивы](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) или [коллекции](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).

Конкретно в вашем случае я бы рекомендовал использовать одну из реализаций [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html): [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) или [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

У вас должен быть какой-то обработчик события что подключился новый Player и в это месте надо создавать новый экземпляр класса Player и записывать его в коллекцию.

Comment: Не могли бы вы простенький пример написать? Чтобы я уловил, как создавать всегда новый экземпляр класса

Comment: @Ilya `new Player()` - создаст новый экземпляр класса

Comment: Это понятно, я имею ввиду разные имена для классов, чтобы их можно было полноценно использовать. Мне ведь нужно будет обращаться к каждому из них, чтобы брать что-то

Comment: Прочитай в учебнике главу про массивы, там есть примеры. Никто здесь пересказывать базовые понятия из учебника не будет.